# Binding parameters in Perl dbi results in foreign key constraint fail

Tags: mysql, perl, parameters, dbi

I have this idea that i want to make a sub which can take a select query and then copy the results into the same table, but with some important changes. My problem is that some of the tables that i run my sub on has large text fields that contains many different characters, some of which will break my insert statement. I then changed my insert to use parameter binding, but when I did this my query will not run because of some foreign key constraint on my "profile" field:

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`retriever`.`result`, CONSTRAINT `result_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`profile`) REFERENCES `profile` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) at ./create_query.pl line 62.
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`retriever`.`result`, CONSTRAINT `result_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`profile`) REFERENCES `profile` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Some information about the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `result` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `profile` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    CONSTRAINT `result_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`profile`) REFERENCES `profile` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1037028383 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is my code:

```
#Define which rows to change
my $rows_to_change = {
    'profile'               => 621420,
};

#Define a select query, the results will then be copied over
my $sql = "select * from result where profile = 639253";

#Define which table to work with
my $table = "result";
my @inserted_ids = create_insert_query($sql, $table, $rows_to_change);

for my $id (@inserted_ids){
    print $id."\n";
}

$dbh->rollback();
$dbh->disconnect();

sub create_insert_query{
    my $select          = shift;
    my $table           = shift;
    my $rows_to_change  = shift;    
    
    my $result = $dbh->prepare($select);
    $result->execute() or die $dbh->errstr;
    
    my @inserted_ids;
    while(my $row = $result->fetchrow_hashref){
        delete $row->{'id'};
        foreach my $key (keys %{$rows_to_change}){
            $row->{$key} = $rows_to_change->{$key};
        }
        my @fields;
        my @values;
        for my $key (keys %{$row}){
            push(@fields, $key);
            
            if(defined $row->{$key}){
                push(@values, "'$row->{$key}'");
            }else{
                push(@values, "null");
            }
        }
        my $fields_string = join(", ", @fields);
        my $values_string = join(", ", @values);
        my $questionmarks = join( ',', map { '?' } @values );
        my $query = qq[insert into $table ($fields_string) values ($questionmarks)];
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute(@values) or die $dbh->errstr;
        
        push(@inserted_ids, $sth->{mysql_insertid});
    }
    return @inserted_ids;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What to do

You want instead something like:

```
$fieldnames   = join ', ' => map { $dbh->quote_identifier($_) } keys %row;
$placeholders = join ', ' => map { '?' } values %row;
...
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO t ($fieldnames) VALUES ($placeholders)');
$sth->execute(values %row);
```

(The [quote_identifier](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#quote_identifier) call is there for safety in case your column names conflict with keywords or need special encoding or quoting.)

### Why?

Your instant problem is that you are quoting values you then bind to placeholders (which binds the value *with the quotes*) and that you bind the string "null" to placeholders (which binds the *string* "null").  This fails some foreign key constraint, since your FKEY is probably not the literal string "null" nor is it a string representing quoted digits (e.g., it's probably the number 123 and not the string with embedded quotes "'123'").

For reference, binding strings, strings containing quotes, numeric literals, and `undef` under the DBI typically works like so:

```
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO t (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
 $sth->execute("'quoted'", 'null', undef, 123, "a string");
 # Approximately the same as:
 #  INSERT INTO t (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ('''quoted''', 'null', NULL, 123, 'a string');
 #                                        ^           ^      ^     ^     ^
 #               a string with quotes ----+           |      |     |     |
 #                                                    |      |     |     |
 #               a string (not the NULL value) -------+      |     |     |
 #                                                           |     |     |
 #               NULL (not the string 'null')----------------+     |     |
 #                                                                 |     |
 #               numeric literal ----------------------------------+     |
 #                                                                       |
 #               another string -----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: quote_identifier helps with more than encoding - it allows columns named e.g. `values`